# Apache <Directory> not applying to subdirectories

Tags: linux, apache, directory, linux-mint

I'm running the latest Apache Server on Linux Mint 14 and trying to take my first babysteps with vhosts, where I encountered a general problem with my setup:

every option I declare in the <Directory> section doesn't seem to have any effect on any subdirectories - but as far as I know and according to the documentation it should.

For example: I'm trying to give permissions for .htaccess file by

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

a .htaccess in /var/www would work properly, but e.g. a .htaccess in /var/www/test with contents "Deny from all" would take no effect.

Are there any options I have to set that I don't know of? This isn't my first apache setup so I'm kind of confused right now, but I can't find a solution.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, apache2.conf includes external vhost settings, so the default settings in sites-available/default kept overwriting mine.